# shelf life dressing with shalots

Tags: storage-lifetime

I understand that one should not keep homemade salad dressing that contains garlic for a period longer than a week or so. Does this also apply to using shallots in the dressing?

Answer (score 1):

Botulism is a concern when garlic (or shallot...or even fresh herbs) is stored in oil at **room temperature**. An acidic environment virtually eliminates the  risk, meaning that garlic, shallot, and herbs are safe in a vinaigrette (especially one that separates and has those ingredients mainly sitting in the vinegar layer), for example.  Refrigeration makes the whole thing even safer.  You might also take a look at [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/how-long-does-it-take-botulism-spores-to-germinate-in-the-fridge).  In general, shallot should be treated the same as garlic when considering the risks of botulism.

Answer (score 0):

In my fairly extensive experience with vinaigrettes in commercial kitchens, garlic tends to turn well before shallots in vinaigrettes.